# Get all emails from Oulook using GgraphServiceClient api

Tags: c#, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api

I want all emails from outlook with date filter and if has attachment.

```
GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(
             new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
             {
                 requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", externalUserLogin.AccessToken);
                 return Task.FromResult(0);
             }));
        IUserMessagesCollectionPage pagedMessages;
        var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
        {
            new QueryOption("ReceivedDateTime", $"2022-01-01..2022-10-12"),
            new QueryOption("hasattachment", "true")
        };
         pagedMessages = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Messages
                   .Request(queryOptions)
                   .Select(msg => new
                   {
                       msg.Subject,
                       msg.BodyPreview,
                       msg.ReceivedDateTime,
                       msg.HasAttachments,
                       msg.Attachments,
                       msg.Id
                   })
                   .Expand("attachments")
                   .Top(50)
                   .OrderBy("receivedDateTime desc")
                   .GetAsync();
        foreach (var item in pagedMessages.CurrentPage)
        {
            if (item.Attachments != null && item.Attachments.Any())
            {
                foreach (var attachment in item.Attachments)
                {
                    if (attachment.ODataType == "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment")
                    {
                        FileAttachment fileAttachment = attachment as FileAttachment;
                        byte[] contentBytes = fileAttachment.ContentBytes;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I already tried, but the filter is not working as expected. I got all emails with attachment and without attachment.

I want all emails without take.

I added ".Expand("attachments")", So I have to call the attachment API separately or I get attachments?

Answer (score 0):

if your trying to use $search as a Query option then your code isn't correct it should be

```
    var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
    {
        new QueryOption("$search", $"received>=2022-01-01 AND received<=2022-10-12 AND hasattachment:true"),
    };
```

the KQL keyword for is ReceivedDateTime is received https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/keyword-queries-and-search-conditions?view=o365-worldwide while the between ... operator should be supported I think its discouraged and didn't work for me (although i have used it in the past in EWS)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solutions. I am getting all the emails using Filter. I used query options, but it is not working. Below is complete solutions for is read, has attachment, filter by date and update email after inserting your local db.

```
/// <summary>
    /// Gets a mail from Outlook
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="token">Token</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task<IList<Message>> GetEMails(string token)
    {
        IUserMessagesCollectionPage pagedMessages;
        List<Message> emailMessages = new List<Message>();

        GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(
             new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
             {
                 requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
                 return Task.FromResult(0);
             }));
        
        pagedMessages = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Messages
                   .Request()
                   .Filter($"ReceivedDateTime ge 2022-01-01 and receivedDateTime lt 2022-01-31 and hasAttachments eq true and isRead eq false")
                   .Select(msg => new
                   {
                       msg.Body,
                       msg.Subject,
                       msg.BodyPreview,
                       msg.ReceivedDateTime,
                       msg.Attachments,
                       msg.Id,
                       msg.CcRecipients,
                       msg.BccRecipients,
                       msg.From,
                       msg.ToRecipients
                   })
                   .Expand("attachments")
                   .Top(10)
                   .OrderBy("receivedDateTime desc")
                   .GetAsync();
        
        emailMessages.AddRange(pagedMessages.CurrentPage);
        
        while (pagedMessages.NextPageRequest != null)
        {
            pagedMessages = await pagedMessages.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
            emailMessages.AddRange(pagedMessages.CurrentPage);
        }
        return messages;
    }

/// <summary>
    /// Update is Message Mark as Read
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">Message ID</param>
    /// <param name="_graphServiceClient">Graph Service Client</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private async Task MarkAsRead(string id, GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient)
    {
        try
        {
            await _graphServiceClient.Me
              .Messages[id]
              .Request()
              .Select("IsRead")
              .UpdateAsync(new Message { IsRead = true });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _customLogger.Error(ex.Message, ex);
        }
    }
```